# Append a string URL in item object in python scrapy code

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I want to append string url in the item :
`object(item['urls'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract())`

Example:
`item['urls'] = "http://lakmeindia.com" + sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()`

```
# Item class

import scrapy

class LakmeSampleItem(scrapy.Item):
     urls = scrapy.Field()
     catagory = scrapy.Field()
     sub_category = scrapy.Field()

# lakme Spider
import scrapy

from LakmeProject.items import LakmeSampleItem

class LakmeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "lakme"
    allowed_domains = ["lakmeindia.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.lakmeindia.com/sitemap"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("//div[@class='make-up']/ul[1]/li"):
            item = LakmeSampleItem()
            item['sub_category'] = sel.xpath('span/text()').extract()
            # here i want to append url(because url is coming like [/sitemap])
            item['urls'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['catagory'] = "Lakme Absolute"
            yield item
```

Comment: What's wrong with the example you gave us? Python strings can be added together just like that, so did you get error messages or bad results?

Comment: hello swanson code is working fine but currently in urls attribute url is coming like (/lakme-professional-makeup/lakme-classics/skin-natural-mousse) but i need full url like (ahttp://www.lakmeindia.com/lakme-professional-makeup/lakme-classics/skin-natural-mousse) so i am trying to append ahttp://www.lakmeindia.com before comming url.

Comment: @Ranvijay Are you seeing errors when you do: `item['urls'] = "http://lakmeindia.com" + sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()` ?

Comment: @shaktimaan i get a error message (exceptions.TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. You just need to note that `extract()` returns a list type. So what you actually need to be doing is:

```
item['urls'] = "http://lakmeindia.com" + sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()[0]
```

i.e., get the first item in the list by using `[0]` on the result returned by `extract()`